# Has NLP ever been used to detect if someone is a native (English, or other) speaker?

Tags: nlp

Are there any code samples or papers on the subject? I have not been able to find any resources directly related to the question after a bit of research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears it has. I found two papers [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1211.0498) and [here](http://acl.ldc.upenn.edu/N/N07/N07-2024.pdf), and there are probably other. The second one was published at NAACL (a high-quality conference) and contains a bunch of relevant references.